# C++ std::getline size limit on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, max, getline

I'm having problems with std::getline on Mac OSX Snow Leopard. For some reason it limit the size of the input, while on Debian/Ubuntu it's unlimited size?

```
std::getline(std::cin, input)
```

Any clues about the limit?

Comment: What do you mean there is a limit? What happens when you try to go over the limit?

Comment: The limit (`str.max_size()`) on OS X x64 is 4 exabytes. Seriously doubt that’s the problem. More likely you are hitting a delimiter or EOF.

Comment: What is the actual input and what are you getting in the program? A short compilable piece of code would be nice (you will probably solve your own problem by writing the short code snippet).

Comment: Still unclear the reason, but for sure is not a limit of std::getline().

Comment: Using QT Builder console I can type as many Chars as I want. The issue is only when using Mac OSX Snow Leopard Terminal. It limit the amount of chars you can input. I did not figured out how to increase that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard says this about the `getline` function:

---

**21.3.7.9 Inserters and extractors [lib.string.io]**

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
  basic_istream<charT,traits>&
    getline(basic_istream<charT,traits>& is,
            basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& str,
            charT delim);
```

**Effects:** Begins by constructing a sentry object `k` as if by `basic_istream<charT,traits>::sentry k(is)`. If `bool(k)` is true, it calls
`str.erase()` and then extracts characters from `is` and appends them to `str` as if by calling
`str.append(1,c)` until any of the following occurs:

- end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case, the `getline` function calls
  `is.setstate(ios_base::eofbit)`).
- `c == delim` for the next available input character `c` (in which case, `c` is extracted but not appended) (27.4.5.3)
- `str.max_size()` characters are stored (in which case, the function calls `is.setstate(ios_base::failbit)`) (27.4.5.3)

---

So, the only reasons why you would be getting a short line are (a) your C++ implementation does not conform to the standard (highly unlikely), you're hitting end-of-file, or you're reading a 4 gigabyte line (highly unlikely).

Comment: Mac OS X builds 64-bit by default, so 4 gigabytes should not be the `string::max_size()` limit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the std::getline that differs between the platform (Windows/Unix/Mac OSX). It's how the line terminators are defined over different platforms. It is '\n\r' for Windows-based, '\n' for unix-based and ('\r'?) for MacOS platforms. Try generating your text file (or a test file) using a MacOS editor and examine if you still have a limit in the size of the input using std::getline?

Comment: Your general answer is good, but Macs do not use `\r` as a delimiter. They use `\n` like any Unix system. (In extremely old versions of Mac OS, prior to 2001, you might find `\r` used.)

Comment: On Windows systems, `\r\n` is used, not `\n\r`.  In any case, if the file is opened in text mode, it doesn't matter:  the line ending will be normalized to be `\n` regardless of what the platform line ending is.